# Factory reset: prestigio multipad 7.0 ultra plus tablet pc pmp 36 70b

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, factory-reset, locked-out

How to factory reset prestigio multipad 7.0 ultra plus tablet pc pmp 36 70b?  It boots to gmail sign in page, then it says wrong password, though it's not connected to the internet, it doesn't even let me connect. I need to reset it

**Edit**

usb debugging  mode is not enabled and I am stuck, can't login [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJXFAdh7UJg), and the tablet,isn't booting to recovery

Comment: That looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154): what you really want is not a factory-reset, but passing by that lock, right? So I've just added the `locked-out` tag to your question; in [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) you can find some first-aid and links to useful related questions (I know your issue is solved by the accepted answer, so count this a hint for others coming across your post).

Comment: @Izzy thanks, but i sold the tablet since i couldn't unlock it long ago and accepted the answer that was there, to give him some rep coz he put some effort and voted it up

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Fischer! So my pointer might prove even more helpful then :)

Comment: @Izzy yes you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot access the main UI, but the system powers up, boot in to recovery.

Try and find out what your *recovery* keys are (e.g. it's usually *vol+*, *vol-* and *power* on Samsung phones) online or by reading your device's manual, then holding them as your device boots.

Once in recovery, use the *volume* keys to select an option and *power* to use that tool, unless your device has a *d-pad* or older Android style buttons (*Menu*, *Home* etcetera).

---

**Also**: You can use *adb* to force the device to reboot to recovery mode if it is enabled, like this, in a terminal or command prompt, with the device connected to a USB port on the computer:

`$ path/to/adb reboot recovery` on Linux/Mac OS X; and

`C:\> path\to\adb.exe reboot recovery` on Windows

replace `path/to/adb` or `path\to\adb.exe` with the location of adb found in the Android SDK `platform-tools` folder (the SDK can be downloaded from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html - choose *SDK for an existing IDE*)

Comment: i have the sdk, usb debugging  mode is not enabled and I am stuck, can't login like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJXFAdh7UJg and the tablet,isn't booting to recovery, would I be able to force it using the sdk?

Comment: Maybe you can get it to boot in to a Fastboot envrionment [described on the CM site](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_fastboot_intro) where you you can flash a recovery or hotboot a recovery image _if_ you can find one.

Comment: would  it work without usb debugging enabled?

Comment: although you did not tell me if it works without debugging, and I doubt it would, you gave me some useful info I did not know, so thanks