# I accidentally deleted all applications from my Android phone

Tags: samsung, stock-android

My phone is Samsung S4 mini CLONE GT-i9190 (CHINA)

Accidentally I have deleted all the applications, what I did is that

1. I installed V root on my pc, and through this program  I rebooted my phone.
2. I installed MoboRobo on my pc, and accidentally marked all applications for delete.
3. I went outside and when I came back and saw mobile screen was black, it was lighting (I think there is no any application and mobile has nothing to show that's why it is just lighting)
4. I put out battery and put back and try to turn on and showing Android logo and can listen start up tune, after that the screen is lighting (the display is lighting)
5. My friend told me to install the ODIN 3 program  on your PC and download firmware for GT-i9190 and install in the phone, but my phone is not debugging.

I think my mobile is empty. If you know solution please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you can reset your phone to its factory settings using this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/77088/67135

However, that won't work: it will only wipe `/data`, restoring your phone to it's factory settings, not restoring the entire ROM.

The reason why ODIN did not work is that ODIN only works for *genuine* Samsung phones, with Samsung firmware.

You'll need to get a `update.zip` file for your phone to flash in recovery. Unfortunately, clones don't usually have these files available.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you were trying to root your phone. If this is the case, then part of that process is completely wiping your /data and /system partitions. So yes, all of your applications, pictures, music etc. are gone.

I would recommend reading the documentation you have, and completing the rooting process. Then sign back into Google, and download all your apps from the play store again. (From the slide out drawer on the left side, select My Apps, then slide from right to left to switch from Installed to All. This will show you a list of all the apps you've ever downloaded. Long press on an app, then tap your way down the list, and you can mass reinstall.)

Things you'll need immediately after rooting:
1) a ROM, for a beginner I'd recommend CyanogenMOD, but I'm not sure what is available in Chine
2) Gapps, these are all the essential Google applications. (Play Store, Play Services etc.)

After you root your phone, and put a ROM on it I would highly recommend buying a backup app. I use Titanium Backup Pro, but I'm not sure if it is available where you are from, you'll have to do a little research.

Lastly, once you root your phone, welcome to the wonderful world of root. You can flash custom roms, use the Xposed framework and much more. You can make your phone do tons of stuff that it could not normally do.

Good luck, have fun.

Comment: Looks like you confused a few things: a) one doesn't need a new ROM after rooting (basically, rooting just *adds* a few binaries), b) OP removed *SYSTEM* apps (not "user apps"), so the device doesn't boot up completely, and no install from Play (or "completing the rooting process", for that) is possible) – OK, and *that* makes him needing a ROM ;)